# How To Not Raise Error from Other File If a Command Already Has Error Function?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want the error_handler.py file to not raise the MissingRequiredArgument error when the unban command already has `@unban.error` function. Is that possible?

Example:

mod.py

```
@unban.error
    async def unban_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(":x: Provide the full username or ID you would like to unban!")
```

error_handler.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(f":x: Missing required argument: {error.param.name}.")
```

I want the error_handler.py to not raise MissingRequiredArgument error when `unban` command is invoked with missing arguments if `unban` command already has `@unban.error` function in mod.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've already figured it out. So to prevent commands with local handlers being handled in global error handler, write this code:

```
if hasattr(ctx.command, 'on_error'):
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

If a discord.py command has already been handled by a local handler it will have a `handled` attribute saying so, in your global error handler you can check for this, and return out of the function (or handle it however you see fit) if it has been handled:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if getattr(error, "handled", False):  # The handled attribute is not guaranteed to be there, so we use getattr with a default value of False
            return

        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(f":x: Missing required argument: {error.param.name}.")
```